# For loop in react render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want create paging link for my grid.I pass maxPages(number) property to component but i cant use for in render method. What can i do ?

```
var Pagination = React.createClass({

render: function(){


    return(
    <div class="text-center">
        <ul class="pagination">

            <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
            {for (var i=0;i <10;i++;)
            {
              return( <li><a href="#">i + 1 </a></li>);
            }
            }

            <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>);

}});
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can run the loop before the rendering  (note that there's an error in your `for` loop)

```
var lis = [];

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    lis.push(<li><a href="#">{i + 1}</a></li>);
}

var Pagination = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div class="text-center">
                <ul class="pagination">

                    <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
                    {lis}
                    <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/69z2wepo/7037/)

Comment: Note that putting components outside of render and then using them in render will break some things in 0.13 (0.14 is changing this).

Answer (score 10):

You can only embed expressions into JSX.

```
<ul className="pagination">{children}</ul>
```

is converted to something like

```
React.createElement('ul', {className: 'pagination'}, children);
```

Do you see now how you could never have a `for` loop in place of `children`? Statements cannot be inside a function call expression.

You can create an array beforehand, like [adeneo showed in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859470/218196).

Comment: And strangely enough, running `map` works because it returns an array -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/69z2wepo/7038/

Comment: Yes, because `Array(10).join().split(',').map(...)` is an expression :) `React.createElement('ul', {className: 'pagination'}, Array(10).join().split(',').map(...));` is not a syntax error.

Comment: Aha, so `createElement` accepts a single child, an array of children or text content, and any expression returning one of those are valid.

Comment: This JSX converting stuff is clever !

Comment: It is! It's just the right amount of magic :) (my personal opinion)