# Simple for loop in react This code gives Errors at for loop

Tags: reactjs, for-loop

This gives Error at for loop

```
let contact=[{name:"Mithun"},{name:"Keerthana"},{name:"Jayendara"},{name:"Shivani"}]

for (i=0;i<list;i++)

{
 <h1>{content[0].name}</h1>
}
```

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149169/how-to-loop-and-render-elements-in-react-js-without-an-array-of-objects-to-map   
 2)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859380/for-loop-in-react-render-method      3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use contact.length rather than list in the for loop. You also need to use cont**a**ct[i] rather than cont**e**nt[0].

```
for (i = 0; i < contact.length; i++) {
    <h1>{contact[i].name}</h1>
}
```

If you are using TSX (TypeScript + React), you can use the map function to make this easier.

```
return contact.map(c => <h1>{c.name}</h1>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you a few things

1. In your question you are looping over `list` rather than that you should be looping over `contacts`
2. As I understand you wish to craete a JSX element from the contact objects. So you need to push it into an array and then render it like

Code:

```
let contact=[{name:"Mithun"},{name:"Keerthana"},{name:"Jayendara"},{name:"Shivani"}]
var content = [];
for (i=0;i<contact;i++)
{
 content.push(<h1>{contact[i].name}</h1>);
}
```

and when you want to render this in your render function you will do something like

```
return (
   <div>{content}</div>
)
```

3. However since you are using react you should be using map function which are more convient and easy to use

Your code will look like

```
 render() {
     return(
         <div>
            {contacts.map(function(item) {
                 return (<h1>{item.name}</h1>)
            })}
         </div>
     )
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to offer a TypeScript solution in addition to the JavaScript ones above.

```
const getCustomerRows = (customers: []): Array<any> => {
    const rows: Array<any> = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
      rows.push(<YourComponent
      name={customerName}
      age={customerAge}
      ></YourComponent>)
     }
    
     return rows;
 }


...
<header>Some Header</header>
{getViewerBkgrdRows().map((row) => row)}
<div>some div</div>
```